# How to extend/alter layout of select Item selection pop up when we add component presentations to a page?

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

Requirement is to change default size, division of the layout etc.

Can someone point to the file where customization need to be done.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to make a GUI Extension to achieve this, but it's very simple. (If you need to know how to make the extension itself, let me know)

The configuration file of the extension must be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge" xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:extensiongroups>
      <cfg:extensiongroup name="Test.Extensions.Group">
        <cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.InsertComponentPresentation">
          <cfg:insertafter>Test.Extensions.Resources</cfg:insertafter>
        </cfg:extension>
      </cfg:extensiongroup>
    </cfg:extensiongroups>
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Test.Extensions.Resources">
        <cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:file type="style">/Style/Custom.css</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
    </resources>
    <definitionfiles/>
  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
    <ext:editorextensions />
  </extensions> 
    <commands />
    <contextmenus/>
  <localization></localization>
    <settings>
        <defaultpage />
        <navigatorurl />
        <editurls/>
        <listdefinitions/>
        <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path></path>
      <resourcegroup />
    </theme>     
    <resourceextensions>
      <resourceextension>Test.Extensions.Group</resourceextension>
    </resourceextensions>
    <customconfiguration></customconfiguration>
  </settings> 
</Configuration>
```

The important things:

- The view you are extending: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.InsertComponentPresentation
- The css file you want to apply: Custom.css

For example I try with:

```
.dashboard #TreePanel
{
    width: 450px !important;
}
```

in my Custom.css and I can change the vertical separator.

If you want to view the `css` or the `aspx` of the actual view you want to extend, to see how you can change the style, they are in:

> TRIDION_HOME\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\Popups\InsertComponentPresentation